# clear/reset formData() using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use formData below, and pass the results. But data is duplicated if the user does it more than once. So I have to clear/reset the formData before adding any value.

I can do it one-by-one like f.name = '', I have tons of keys. Is there any better way to solve the problem?

```
$('input').change(function(){
// Create a new formdata but at first have to clear/reset it
var fd = new FormData();
var f = $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data);
f.name = file.name;
fd.append($('#area input').attr('name'), f);
})
```

Comment: I think you can't clear the result.
You'll have to recreate it

Answer (score 12):

@gurvinder372's answer won't remove your keys from your FormData, it will just set it to an empty string, which is not the same server side.
E.g, in php, `if ( isset($_POST["yourKey"]) )` will still evaluate to true.

---

The best crossbrowser way is unfortunately to create a new FormData object in your situation.

```
fd = new FormData();
```

---

An other possibility, though it's currently only supported by *Chrome>=50* and *Firefox>=39*, is to use the [`formData.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) method.
This will replace the value at set key, or append it if no such key is there.

```
formData.set('yourKey', yourValue);
```

---

Now to answer the title of the question, in *Chrome>=50* and *Firefox>=44*, you can use [`for .. of formData.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/keys#Example) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete) methods of your FormData Object :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('yourKey', yourValue);

for (var key of formData.keys()) {
    // here you can add filtering conditions
    formData.delete(key)
    });
```

or even with its `forEach` method (apparently with the same poor browser support)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('yourKey', yourValue);

formData.forEach(function(val, key, fD){
    // here you can add filtering conditions
    formData.delete(key)
    });
```

Comment: formData is not a new technology, is there isn't any solution to clear it easily? so what people normally do is just to hard reload the page?

Comment: `for of`? should it be `for in`?

Comment: @MariaJane, edited since I missed a part of your question, actually, when availbale in your case, you should use `fd.set()`. No [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is ES6 syntax and loops through iterable objects. `FormData.keys()` returns an Iterator Object, so you have to use this loop. And no, people don't hard reload the page, they just create a new Object (`alreadyReferencedFormData = new FormData();`). And yes, this technology is still in active development, and may change in near future when more UAs will fully implement it

Comment: fd = new FormData(); worked for me, it just recreate the same form but empty.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can clear the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) by doing

```
function clearFormData( fd )
{
  for( var prop in fd )
  {
    if ( typeof fd[ prop ] != "function" )
    {
      fd[ prop ] = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Another approach using [enteries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) and [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete) method

```
var entries = formData.entries();
for(var pair of entries ) 
{
   formData.delete( pair[0] );
}
```

Comment: after I run this function, I do fd.append it says fd.append is not a function. Hmm

Comment: @MariaJane Oh, you can include a check to see if it is a funciton. Check updates

Comment: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: fdfd? is that a typo?

Comment: @MariaJane yes, it was a typo. check now.

Comment: same problem, fd.append is not a function

Comment: hello? any clue why is it so?

Comment: This won't delete the keys, they'll still be sent in the PostData of the request, and server side will still see it (e.g in php `if ( isset($_POST["yourKey"]) )` will still evaluate to true).

Comment: @MariaJane sorry for the delayed reply, there was a change required in the if condition. I have done so, please check.

Answer (score 2):

The way these old posts just stick around not helping anyone...To clear the form, just call the reset method on it.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete by each key outside the iterator(=formData.keys()) like as follows.

```
const keys = [];
for (const key of formData.keys()) {
    keys.push(key);
}
for (const idx in keys) {
    formData.delete(keys[idx]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this FormData.prototype extension

```
Object.defineProperties(FormData.prototype, {
load: {
    value: function (d) {
        switch (true) {
            case d instanceof HTMLFormElement: // form
                d.find("[name]").forEach(i => {
                    this.delete(i.name);
                    this.append(i.name, i.value);
                });
                break;
            case d.__proto__ && d.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("value"): // input, textarea ,x-check etc
                this.delete(d.name);
                this.append(d.name, d.value);
                break;
            default: // raw object
                for (var v in d) {
                    this.delete(v);
                    // previn trimitere de tag
                    !(d[v] || {}).tagName && this.append(v, typeof d[v] === 'string' ? d[v] : JSON.stringify(d[v]));
                }
                break;
        }
    },
    enumerable: true
},
clear: {
    value: function () {
        var k = [];
        for (var key of this.keys()) {
            k.push(key);
        }
        k.map(key=>this.delete(key));
    },
    enumerable: true
},
rename: {
    value: function (entrie, to) {
        if (this.getAll(entrie).length > 1) {
            throw Error("FormData can't rename multiple values! ");
        }
        let orig = this.get(entrie);
        gettype(orig) === "File" ? this.append(to, orig, to) : this.append(to, orig);
        this.delete(entrie);
    },
    enumerable: true
},
list: {
    get: function () {
        let o = {};
        for (let [k, v] of this.entries()) {
            var found = this.getAll(k);
            o[k] = found.length > 1 ? found : this.get(k);
        }
        return o;
    },
    enumerable: true
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fd;
$('input').change(function(){
// Create a new formdata but at first have to clear/reset it
fd = new FormData();
var f = $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data);
f.name = file.name;
fd.append($('#area input').attr('name'), f);
})

fd.delete($('#area input').attr('name'));
```