# Data duplicate when send request second time

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

I send file to server by this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('folder', 'html')
fd.append('permission', 0)
fd.append("file", file, file.name)
```

I take file from input,
My request is

```
$.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                         url: getURI("fileupload"),
                          success: function (data) {
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                               callback(data.body.url, {
                                alt: ''
                              });
                             };
                             reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                          },
                          error: function (error) {
          // handle error
              },
                async: true,
                  data: fd,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  timeout: 60000
                });
```

1) Send file is ok
2) File 2 send: it sended, but it try send first FormData, if I try send 5 files, it will send latest, but will try to send 4 previos.

How to remove previos FormData??

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: getURI("fileupload"),
    success: function (data) {
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            callback(data.body.url, {
                alt: ''
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        //
        // Clear file input here
        //
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // handle error
    },
    async: true,
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    timeout: 60000
});
```

In success callback you should clear manualny your file input. More information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450155/how-to-clear-reset-formdata-using-javascript)

After that create new fd instance of FormData:

```
fd = new FormData();
```

More about clearing FormData objects you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575435/clear-reset-formdata-using-javascript)